# label gets cut on ggplot2 bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, geom-bar

I created a ggplot2 bar plot  and added a label, with the bar y-value, above the bar.

```
d <- data.frame(
       Ano=2000+5*0:10,
       Populacao =c(6.1,6.5,6.9,7.3,7.7,8.0,8.3,8.6,8.9,9.1,9.3)
     )
d %>% ggplot(aes(x=Ano, y=Populacao)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label=Populacao), vjust=-0.5)
```

[image]

Notice how the label on the highest column gets cut.

Is there a way for the plot to automatically adjust to the presence of the label?

EDIT: I know I can adjust this manually with `scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 10, 1), limits=c(0,10))`

Comment: Semi-automatic solution would be to use something like `expand_limits(y = max(d$Populacao * 1.05))`.